# 3GP/AMR mix/merge tracks

Tags: android, audio, mixing, 3gp, amr

Is there an easy way to merge 2 3gp (amr) audio files into a single audio file?

I need them to be synchronous/over top of each other not one after the other.  I am using android to do this.  I have heard somewhere that for some audio formats you can simply add the bytes (being careful that you dont get a too high or too low result).  Is this true with the 3gp/amr format on android?

Answer (score 0):

Android only allows playback/recording of 3GP/AMR files. To mix audio you will need the decoded PCM data. This means you have to decode both streams mix (this is indeed adding + normalizing) and then playback. 
The bad side - there no way to get access to the build in AMR decoder which allows you to decode without playback.

So ... no easy way.